# How to access the Redux store from deeply nested components

Tags: reactjs, nested, redux

I'm new to Redux and my nested component structure is shown below. I have a Redux container which owns the state and renders Component A. Component A renders Component B and Component B renders Component C.

```
- Redux Container
  - Dumb Component A          <-- Child of Redux Container
    - Dumb Component B        <-- Child of Component A
      -  Dumb Component C     <-- Child of Component B
```

Components A, B and C need to access the Redux store to update the state. How can I go about doing this? I don't want to change each dumb component into containers. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Just pass down the props your dumb component needs ?

Comment: Hey WilomGfx, is it possible for Component C send the Redux container a value to update to the store? I believe the Redux container and Component C can't talk to each other as Component C is rendered by Component B.

Comment: Its doable, but you may want to to rethink your structure, your dumb components should just be provided with everything they need to modify state. They should only care for rendering and binding events to actions(which should come from the ''smart component'' or the container in your case.

Comment: The components are designed based on my JSON data structure. The object has properties that contain nested arrays up to 3 levels deep. So would you think I'd need to also redesign my JSON structure? Thanks for your help btw :)

Comment: It depends, but probably. I'd have see it in order to help you more than that, but yeah. No problem btw :)!

Comment: Awesome, I'll rethink my JSON structure. Appreciate your help!

Comment: No problem. I'll post my answer and you can accept if that's okay with you ? That way we get a closed question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should feel free to use `connect()` around any of your components that you feel need to directly access data from the Redux store, or dispatch actions to Redux.  It's also okay if you have fewer connected components, and pass data and action creators down to children as props, but one of the main reasons for `connect` is that you can use it to wrap up *any* component in your application that needs to interact with Redux.

Also, don't over-think the "container/presentational" concept too much.  Dan Abramov has said that [people spend too much time worrying about it](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/802569801906475008), and I have [a chat log where I discuss realistic practices for using `connect` and defining "containers"](https://gist.github.com/markerikson/ea312b5ee398627ffceb09f89904831f).

For more info, see:

- The [Redux FAQ entry on connecting multiple components](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/ReactRedux.html#react-multiple-components)
- The [Redux Architecture](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/redux-architecture.md) and [Redux Performance](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/react-performance.md#redux-performance) sections of my [React/Redux links list](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links)
- My blog post [Practical Redux, Part 6: Connected Lists, Forms, and Performance](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/01/practical-redux-part-6-connected-lists-forms-and-performance/)

Comment: While you can use `connect` this doesn't solve the problem of *what* to connect. For example a modal with a *datepicker*. such modal could be "called" from any other component on the page, and the deep child ("datepicker") of should dispatch a change to a very SPECIFIC place in the store, which is related to the "thing" which that triggered the datepicker modal in the first place.

Comment: Please see my post [Practical Redux, Part 10: Managing Modals and Context Menus](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/07/practical-redux-part-10-managing-modals/), which demonstrates how to solve that _exact_ use case.

Comment: Your blog post is more like a book, it's insanely long. it would take hours to read -> understand -> digest -> remember. If there was a single paragraph you can point me to that touches this exact point, it would help

Comment: It's not _that_ long :)  I would encourage you to actually read the post, because it explains both the general principles of 1) Using descriptive objects and a central component to manage which modals are showing, 2) Triggering showing a modal from any component, and 3) Handling a "response" value from a Redux-connected modal.  All of these pieces are necessary to understand how this approach works. That said, you may want to focus on the 'Using the Dialog Result Value" section.